# How does Google force HTTPS on their .app TLD?

Tags: dns

In I/O 2018 Google announced their new .app TLD and they said that it will be HTTPS only.

I thought that DNS just maps domain names to IP's.

How are they forcing HTTPS?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

(a little offtopic here)

It is called HSTS Preloading, see https://hstspreload.org/

HSTS (HTTP Strict Transport Security) is a way for servers to reply to clients: please contact me over HTTPS only (see https://www.troyhunt.com/the-6-step-happy-path-to-https/ for examples). It enhances security but still does not solve one case: the first connection to a given server can happen over HTTP before the browser learns it should have done an HTTPS instead.

Hence come the "preloading" of HSTS.

Basically this is an hardcoded list embarked in all major browsers code 
(see https://caniuse.com/#feat=stricttransportsecurity for compatibility depending on browser and version, or see at bottom for links to code[1]) that says which domains/TLD are HSTS enabled, which means no HTTP connection allowed to them at all.

Note that:

1. Anyone can submit names to this list by following some requirements, see https://hstspreload.org/#submission-requirements
2. Google (as it started with Chrome but it is now spread among browsers) welcome inclusion of TLDs and not only hostnames, see end of document at https://hstspreload.org/ ("TLD Preloading")

They already did add `.DEV` in the past (the TLD by itself is not live yet, but Google will launch it "soon") which broke many developers setup where they used (wrongly) a `.DEV` domain name to name their local resources and as soon as their browsers were updated with the newer HSTS preloading list, they refused to connect to their local `.DEV` host without HTTPS. You can find here and elsewhere (ex: https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/) many horror stories of developers up in arms against that and also may people offering bad solutions for that (like disabling HSTS preloading which is a very bad idea).

Also when you buy a `.APP` domain name (and it will be same for `.DEV`), Google (as registry of `.APP`) made sure contractually with all registrars that they will, during checkout of a `.APP` domain name buy, display a prominent message saying something along the line of: ".APP is a secure TLD and websites will only work with an SSL certificate(sic); make sure to buy an SSL certificate" (SSL certificate is straight out of Google documentation and this is very sad to read out of them since it is a doubly wrong term, it should have been an "X.509 certificate" or, in order not to frighten anyone, at least a "certificate used for TLS communications", noone should use SSL anymore nowadays...).

By the way, `.APP` opened for the public at standard prices yesterday, May 8th.

Of course all of that is only related to web browsing. You could set any other kind of service, like email, on top of a `.APP` domain name, without any mandatory TLS (which of course is not a good idea nowadays but nothing will refrain you from doing that). For email, there is ongoing discussion to have basically HSTS but for MTAs, see https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-ietf-uta-mta-sts/

[1] see some source codes with the HSTS preloading list:

- https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/net/+/master/http/transport_security_state_static.json
- https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/security/manager/ssl/nsSTSPreloadList.inc

or you can use the API at https://hstspreload.com/ to learn if a name is on the list

Comment: Last link in answer (https://hstspreload.com/) is dead - *"DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN"*.

Answer (score 3):

It's just a policy. A domain name is a domain name, and DNS only cares about how the name is translated to other resources, like for example an IP address. Technically any IP address can be used together with any IP protocol (there are 256 to choose from, one of which is TCP) and when applicable, any port number (there are 65536 to choose from, two of which are HTTP and HTTPS respectively). There is no way to place restrictions on this via DNS, but of course the TLD registrar can attempt to do this via policy rules.

By trial and error I easily found an .app domain where HTTPS is not enforced:

```
curl -v -L http://foo.app/
```

This results in a couple of redirects, but none of them redirect to HTTPS, and the final response is a HTTP response from a GoDaddy address.

Comment: You are missing part of the problem, as this is not so much related to DNS but the specific application protocol, HTTP(S). Also command line web clients are probably not using the HSTS preloading list (I have not double checked). They probably should...

Comment: Granted that Google's policy rules combine Google's role as a browser vendor with their entirely separate role as a DNS registrar. HSTS preloading lists are however specific to individual applications, so it would be misleading to make anyone believe that .app is HTTPS-only just because Google owns the TLD. Not saying your answer is wrong however, I am upvoting it.

Comment: It is indeed a specific case because Google is also author of a browser, but, see my answers and links, Firefox, Edge, Safari are also using the exact same list, so the symptoms will be the same whatever browser you use. Only command line clients may behave differently. Even if Google was not owning chrome, they could ask to add their TLD in the list and be taken into account by all browsers. But thanks for the upvote :-) (even Tor uses it: https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor-browser.git/plain/security/manager/ssl/nsSTSPreloadList.inc?h=tor-browser-52.3.0esr-7.5-2 )

Comment: It's not just command-line clients, there is also a huge amount of server-to-server traffic, not to speak of the security catastrophe known as "Internet of Things"...

Comment: I agree. HSTS is still a newer addition, so it might progressively get added to more software. Otherwise same problems as the one exposed for TLS here: https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~shmat/shmat_ccs12.pdf  ; but "internal" clients - not human driven - could be hardcoded with https:// URLs right at the beginning, hence solving the problem even without HSTS.