# How to redirect HTTP URL with IP address to HTTPS URL with domain name?

Tags: http, nginx, https, redirect

How to redirect an URL such as `http://192.0.2.4` to `https://example.com` and not `https://192.0.2.4` in Nginx?

Like Google is doing by redirecting `https://172.217.7.206` to `https://google.com`

My nginx configuration:

```
#Redirect all traffic to HTTPS

  server {
  listen 80 default_server;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } 

 server {

    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name  www.example.com;
```

I don't want any rewrite because it cost more resources.

Comment: when you redirect to $host you redirect to the same host that has arrived. if you want to redirect to your own host, return 301 https://example.com$request_uri; to redirect to the host you want.

Comment: Sorry but because of the ip address is not accepted by ssl, nginx is not redirecting the HTTPS request.

Comment: Isn't the answer I just put down there right?

Comment: I just found an answer on another question, actually It's not possible through nginx.       https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50258202/how-does-google-force-https-on-their-app-tld/50258651#50258651

Comment: I thought you asked this: https://serverfault.com/questions/629045/nginx-redirect-ip-address-to-domain-name Close, the question if it's already asnwered, and great you managed to find it, thanks for the info :D

Comment: Your answer is right for HTTP request, not HTTPS.

Comment: Oh, okay, someone edited it and put it as "http" , just edited it to be clear that you want https and not http.

Answer (score 0):

## Redirect all traffic to HTTPS

If the only domain you recive in your server is www.example.com, this solution should work for you. This listens to the "ip" and redirects it to www.example.com.

```
server {
    server_name 192.0.2.4;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```