# I don't know why request in browser change to https but in curl it works

Tags: curl, browser, configuration

I make a request with `curl http://mysite.app` and I get the response, but when I put the URL in the browser it redirects to `https://mysite.app` with this response headers

```
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 307 Internal Redirect
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

I don't know why this is happening, and who is redirecting the request to https?
If anything was wrong with the DNS setting, server configuration, ... I could not get the response through curl?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After doing a lot of research is see a comment that said about .dev domains and that they are secure and can not get HTTP access to them so I found out that .app is also one of those which only allows HTTP

Comment: Man, U saved my day!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50258202/how-does-google-force-https-on-their-app-tld

Comment: What you meant to say was 'only allows HTTPS*', .app does not allow insecure traffic